# Python3.8 tkinter blocks thread from calling Stringvar.get() when using thread.join()

Tags: tkinter, python-multithreading, python-3.8

I've heard `tkinter` isn't thread safe, but I don't understand the current problem I'm facing.  I have a `tkinter` GUI in Python that has a `tkinter.Stringvar` `var`, and a button <kbd>Run</kbd> which builds a thread that calls a function `fn`.

```
import tkinter,threading
from time import sleep as Sleep

gui=tkinter.Tk() 
  
var=tkinter.StringVar(gui) #create a tkinter string variable
var.set('Hello')

def print_sequence():
    current_var=var.get()
    print(current_var)

def run(): #build thread and start
    thread=threading.Thread(target=fn)
    thread.start()
    # thread.join() 
    print('Done!')
    

def fn():
    print(var.get())
    Sleep(2)
    print('done fn')

add_btn=tkinter.Button(gui, text='Run', command=run)
add_btn.grid(column=2,row=1)

gui.mainloop()
```

Running the code above returns 'Hello' as expected when the <kbd>Run</kbd> button is pressed. However, this won't be the case if you uncomment the `thread.join()` line. This seems to send the code into an infinite loop.

Why can't the thread retrieve the state of a `tkinter` variable when calling the thread's `join` method?

Comment: Because both are in two different threads?

Answer (score 2):

Based on the tkinter source code, `get()` sends an event to the main event loop and waits for the reply.

You are calling `get()` and blocking the event loop with `join()` so `get()` never completes.

You can check the source code here:
https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/master/Lib/tkinter/

If you search the source code, you will see the function chain:

`get()` calls `globalgetvar()` which calls `Tkapp_GlobalGetVar()` which calls `var_invoke()`. The final function blocks until the event is processed.